# espacios a la derecha al pasar datos a input text en modal

Tags: php, html, bootstrap

este es mi caso espero me puedan ayudar

tengo una tabla la cual lleno con datos desde mysql, cada fila tiene un boton que despliega una ventana modal la cual lleva los datos de la fila sobre la que se dio click en el boton. Todo funciona bien salvo que me deja un numero considerables de espacios en blanco a la izquierda del dato que lleva y no se como quitarlos, ya intente usando trim para quitarlos pero no lo consigo.

Esta es la forma en que lleno la tabla

```html
<table class="table table-striped" id="info-tabla">
                        <thead>
                            <th style="width:80px;">Nombre</th>
                            <th style="width:40px;">Rol</th>
                            <th style="width:60px;">Correo</th>
                            <th style="width:60px;">visualizar</th>
                          
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <?php foreach($consulta as $info): ?>
                            <tr>
                                <td><span id="alias<?php echo $info->getID();?>">
                                        <?php echo $info->getNombre(); ?></span>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <?php echo $info->getRoles(); ?>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <?php echo $info->getCorreo(); ?>
                                </td>
                                <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm  Mostrar" value="<?php echo $info->getID(); ?>"><span>Visualizar</span></button>
                                </td>
                               
                            </tr>
                            <?php 
                        endforeach;
                        ?>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
```

[image: Modal]

```html
<div class="modal fade bd-example-modal-sm" id="mostrar" name="mostrar" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="mostrar" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h6 class="modal-title">Esta viendo:</h6>
                <button class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Cerrar">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="container-fluid">
                    <div class="col-12">
                        <form action="" method="post" class="form-group ">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control crea_data" id="alias" name="alias">
                            <input type="submit" value="Confirmar" id="confirmar" name="confirmar" class="mt-4 btn btn-danger btn-sm btn-guardar">
                        </form>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Como podrán ver deja espacios a la izquierda del dato que debería mostrar

De antemano gracias por la ayuda

Comment: Por favor edita tu pregunta: agrega el CSS que tienes, y si es posible no pongas php, sino el HTML resultante. Me gustaría ayudar.

Comment: Y agrega el codigo de la modal que lo que has puesto tiene pinta de ser la base, no la modal

Comment: Estoy utilizando bootstrap, no tengo ningún css asociado de momento, no se si podria ser este span que agrego a la columna <td><span id="alias<?php echo $info->getID();?>">
                                        <?php echo $info->getNombre(); ?></span>
                                </td>

Comment: Trata poniendo justo despues de tu `<span id="alias<?php echo $info->getID();?>">` el `<?php echo $info->getNombre(); ?>`, sin dejar ningun espacio, sin salto de linea sin nada

Comment: Es bastante probable que el bootsrap te agrege css con las clases form-control crea_data y por eso lo mueve a la derecha. Habria que ver el código final generado.

Comment: Perfecto Edwin Aquitino, era eso que bobada, mi editor coloca en diferentes filas las etiquetas. Muchas Gracias que fácil era, no me había fijado en eso.

Comment: @EdwinAquino Por favor considera mover tu comentario como respuesta para poder ser aceptada como correcta por car-onte

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error puede ser por que estas dejando espacio entre

```
<span id="alias<?php echo $info->getID();?>">
```

y

```
echo $info->getNombre(); ?>
```

Modificalo uno al lado del otro, sin dejar ningun tipo de espacio, salto de linea ni nada.